# Handling outbound call if it's not answered

Tags: java, asterisk, outbound

Hy, I have made a java application using asterisk-java and from it I can receive a call and can initiate outbound as well. But I am facing one problem that whenever I bulk outbound calls to say 50k users, the application can handle only those who answered the calls not those who unanswered or didn't responded. Also as I have set the value of

```
OriginateAction.setAsync(true)
```

in my outbound calling application so I am getting success response to every call, which means call is successfully initiated, but if this value is not set then although I can check the response (error: incase the user didn't responded the call), but then in this case outbound bulk drops from 50k to 3k.

My Ideal solution would be if the call is not answered and is hung up eventually then I can redirect it to some AGI script, which would show its record (hangup cause, Answered/Busy/etc)

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have manage number of call yourself.

Asterisk not designed to know how many calls at once your hardware/trunks can support,that interface just for place SINGLE call.

Check vicidial dialler or other project writed before.